# Finding Old Bitcoin Wallet

Tags: private-key-import

I created a Bitcoin account back in 2014, but my computer crashed a couple of year ago and I don't remember which firm or site I did it through. Not sure if that even matters. I do have the Wallet Name, Wallet Address and Wallet Key, but having difficulty using the data to access my old wallet in my new Coinbase acct. Please help!

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/103688/5406

Answer (score 1):

By Wallet key, do you mean private key ? If you have private key, you can use any bitcoin wallet to import the private key https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys

A common [bitcoin private key](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Private_key) looks like this:

```
5Kb8kLf9zgWQnogidDA76MzPL6TsZZY36hWXMssSzNydYXYB9KF
```

If your key doesn't look like this, its probably a password for the bitcoin service where you created the wallet. You need to locate that service and login into it with Wallet Name/Key to get to those bitcoins.

Comment: The service, Which I don't remember, provided the following: 

Wallet Name: (an alphanumeric username I created utilizing my last name)

Wallet Address: (a 34 character alphanumeric code consisting of lower and uppercase letters)

Wallet Key: A much longer code like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Electrum wallet has a tool for importing funds. After you create a new wallet, you can click on Wallet -> Private keys -> Sweep. In the box that has opened, paste your private key and click on Sweep.

Don't forget to do the same with your Bitcoin Cash funds. Same process applies using Electron Cash wallet.